# Call method in Object

Tags: javascript, json, oop

```
var $ = 
{
  message: function()
   {
     return "Hello World";
   },
   got: this.message()
};
$.got;
```

How to make something like this works.

Comment: *this* is a default property of an execution context. Plain object's don't have a *this* (unless you assign such a property).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`got` needs to be a function for it to execute code:

```
got: function () { this.message(); }

...

$.got();
```

Comment: It works, but can you explain why my example generate error

Comment: Because `this`, in your context, is the global object, not the object.